# Create subgroups within a factor based on the sequencing of another column

Tags: r, tidyverse, data-manipulation

I am attempting to create subgroups within a factor based on a particular column. Here is a  example dataset named "test" similar to the one I am working with.

```
structure(list(old.id = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C"
), id.number = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 1, 2, 3), X = c(0.859207813394842, 0.636238617960869, 0.507899267816508, 
0.400124367809121, 0.867246955862074, 0.620089503630128, 0.493032629079145, 
0.702937523522877, 0.897875765710176, 0.360667580073056, 0.931321208973492, 
0.298666640389948, 0.94444119643156, 0.223731238077921, 0.705733544607941, 
0.354808093410256, 0.196606367677969, 0.67764700709383, 0.510474776312792, 
0.214473998493235), Y = c(44, 41, 43, 61, 41, 51, 55, 34, 41, 
63, 15, 77, 57, 73, 60, 71, 73, 16, 50, 19), Z = c(322, 349, 
395, 300, 368, 357, 385, 306, 385, 377, 323, 335, 314, 372, 372, 
362, 311, 301, 332, 314), Factor1 = c("Y", "N", "N", "N", "Y", 
"N", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "N", "N", "Y", "Y", "Y", "N", "Y", 
"N", "N"), Factor2 = c("L", "M", "H", "L", "H", "L", "L", "M", 
"H", "H", "H", "M", "L", "H", "H", "H", "L", "H", "L", "M")), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

My two main objectives:

1. anonymize the "old.id" column
2. create chains of events with a new "new.id" that are defined by the old.id column and the "id.number" column

If not for the added sequencing of the "id.number" column I could easily anonymize the id by using

```
library(tidyverse)
new_test=test %>%  mutate(new_id=group_indices(.,old.id))
```

I have not been able to determine how to group the results and assign a new id using the "id.number".  Below is the result I am hoping for.

```
structure(list(old.id = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C"
), id.number = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 1, 2, 3), new.id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5), X = c(0.859207813394842, 0.636238617960869, 
0.507899267816508, 0.400124367809121, 0.867246955862074, 0.620089503630128, 
0.493032629079145, 0.702937523522877, 0.897875765710176, 0.360667580073056, 
0.931321208973492, 0.298666640389948, 0.94444119643156, 0.223731238077921, 
0.705733544607941, 0.354808093410256, 0.196606367677969, 0.67764700709383, 
0.510474776312792, 0.214473998493235), Y = c(44, 41, 43, 61, 
41, 51, 55, 34, 41, 63, 15, 77, 57, 73, 60, 71, 73, 16, 50, 19
), Z = c(322, 349, 395, 300, 368, 357, 385, 306, 385, 377, 323, 
335, 314, 372, 372, 362, 311, 301, 332, 314), Factor1 = c("Y", 
"N", "N", "N", "Y", "N", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "N", "N", "Y", 
"Y", "Y", "N", "Y", "N", "N"), Factor2 = c("L", "M", "H", "L", 
"H", "L", "L", "M", "H", "H", "H", "M", "L", "H", "H", "H", "L", 
"H", "L", "M")), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

So if we look when "old.id' =A and the "id.number" field cycles back to 1 it defines a new "chain" of events and is assigned a "new.id" number.   My actual dataset has 60 columns and about 500,000 rows and any solution would need to scale to millions of rows.  I would prefer a tidy solution so I could add it to an existing tidy pipeline but I would appreciate anything that works. Thank you

Comment: `df$new.id <- cumsum(df$id.number == 1)` or in dplyr, `df <- df %>% mutate(new.id = cumsum(id.number == 1))`

Comment: @alistaire  exactly what I need! So clever, really appreciate it.  I am going to turn your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 0):

A really nice solution to my problem was provided by alistaire in the comments above. Here it is:

```
df$new.id <- cumsum(df$id.number == 1) or in dplyr, df <- df %>% mutate(new.id = cumsum(id.number == 1))
```